# JSON input string with double quotes

Tags: python

I have the following JSON request which i need to parse and pull some data from the database, for the sake of the issue please assume that the double quotes within strings are allowed to mark inches how can I ignore the double quotes for string `"test"er"` and simply pass `"tester"`?

```
{
  "searchtype":"search",
  "searchspec":{
    "source":"user",
    "searchstring":"test"er"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `\` before the double quote. Try this:

```
{"searchtype":"search","searchspec":{"source":"user","searchstring":"test\"er"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
{
  "searchtype": "search",
  "searchspec": {
    "source": "user",
    "searchstring": "test\"er\""
  }
}
```

After making changes, you can verify in this link http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: Thanks all for your time. It didn't work with "test\"er". I tried with \\" and it worked, but let's say the input comes in as "test"er" is there a way to replace "test"er" with "test\\"er" before i call the json.loads method to load my JSON string ?